# What is copy filtering mode in ant?

Tags: ant

I'm trying to understand an existing ant script created by someone else. I notice a lot of:

However when trying to read up on API or info on the topic the most I can find is:

> setFiltering(boolean filtering)
>
> Set filtering mode.

http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/ant/api/org/apache/tools/ant/taskdefs/Copy.html

> setFiltering
>
> public void setFiltering(boolean filtering)
>
> Set filtering mode. Parameters: filtering - if true enable filtering;
>   default is false.

http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/ant/api/org/apache/tools/ant/taskdefs/Copy.html#setFiltering(boolean)

Without any explanation of what is actually happening, can anyone shed some light?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This page](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/copy.html) has some more details:

> Indicates whether token filtering using the global build-file filters should take place during the copy. Note: Nested `<filterset>` elements will always be used, even if this attribute is not specified, or its value is false (no, or off).

And the docs for [filters can be found here](https://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html#filters)

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for - there was a token being used with copy filtering on that was causing corruption issues just like this said. Thank you.